# Why does my click function execute when page is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and a a jQuery function like:

```
$('#cadastro-confirmar').click(function(){
   ...
});

<button id="cadastro-confirmar" class=" col-25 button-cadastro confirmar">Confirmar</button>
```

but everytime the page is ready the `.click()` is executed like a `.ready()`. But why?

**EDIT:**

As you asked for I'm posting more code.

The button `id="cadastrar"` triggers a `.fadeIn()` of a modal which the `<button id="cadastro-confirmar" class=" col-25 button-cadastro confirmar">Confirmar</button>` is inside, like so:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var abrir_cadastro = document.getElementById("cadastrar");

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   ...
   <button id="cadastro-confirmar" class=" col-25 button-cadastro confirmar">Confirmar</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that the .click of the `id="cadastro-confirmar"` (the button inside the modal) is, for some reason, executing his function without being clicked AND even without the modal being activated first.

There is no important thing besides this `<button>` inside de modal and there is not another button, div or anything that calls that same function that could actually explain this behavior.

You can use [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrpewo/5cyfsan1/1/) and the **Chrome Development Tools** to **DEBUG** understand.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is not possible without something triggering the callback. Try to recreate it in a Fiddle to show us.

Comment: you should post all your js code

Comment: your funciton; as it; seems correct. You must have something that triggers the click call; that can be a submit or a call to function ;)

Comment: It's not happening in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgtaopph/), as you can see.

Comment: Post more relevant code please

Comment: Maybe try the `$('selector').on('click', function...` method?

Comment: Please edit your question and create a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue

Answer (score 3):

Change your JS code like this

```
$('#cadastro-confirmar').on("click", function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: Why would this make any difference? From the docs on `.click()`, "This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )` ". I can't see why this got four upvotes either.